# After upgrading to the latest RN TypeError: undefined is not an object ( evaluating '_reactNativeCamera.RNCamera.constants.Aspect.fill')

Tags: react-native-camera

After upgrading to the latest RN TypeError: undefined is not an object ( evaluating '_reactNativeCamera.RNCamera.constants.Aspect.fill')

Can anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: Which versions of RN and RN Camera are you using?

Comment: I am using RN Camera 3.13.1